# how to increase counter on radio button is checked ? Android

Tags: java, android

I want to increase counter when radio button is checked by user
for example

```
if(radiobutton.isChecked()== true){
         counter =  counter + 1;
}
```

what might be the proper code for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. OnCheckedChangedListener.

```
RadioButton radioButton;
    radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked)
                counter++;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Cool i am glad it helped. Dont forget to mark the question answered.